# How can I insert dynamic value to URL in cy.visit()?

Tags: javascript, url, cypress

I am trying to insert value to URL which I want to visit. I use this (for example):

```
const idp = '10'
    
cy.visit('http://test.com/aaa/bbb?id=${idp}')
```

but when I run this, it will ends on this `http://test.com/aaa/bbb?id=$%7Bidp%7D`
instead of `id=10`.

Also I am interested how can I get value from URL to variable.

For example I have URL `http://test.com/aaa/bbb?id=5` and I want to create variable idc which will have value 5.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are using the wrong quotes, you need to use backticks to use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
cy.visit(`http://test.com/aaa/bbb?id=${idp}`)
```

You can then use `cy.url()` to get the current URL as a string and use JavaScript to parse the string as normal.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question you need to use backticks(also called grave accents) as outlined in the [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) docs instead of regular quotes. Your line would then look like -

```
cy.visit(`http://test.com/aaa/bbb?id=${idp}`)
```

For the second part of your question, you can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) (Note this DOES NOT work in IE). An example would be -

```
var url = new URL("http://test.com/aaa/bbb?id=5");
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams );
const myParam = urlParams .get('id');
```